# API Integration - How to extract only values from Object Array using JS?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, integration

Need assistance with Javascript - API Integration. I have been trying to pull data off SWAPI (an open API) and fetch the data into our system. I am struggling with something now!

What I am trying to do is get the around 3 country names and get the people's attribute under that country. So fat I was able to get the country names using the following code:

```
(async () => {

  let Name = [];
  let Diameter = [];
  let Resident = [];

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    const PlanetDetails = await api.makeRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${[i]}`,
    });

    Name[i] = PlanetDetails.data.name;
    Resident[i] = PlanetDetails.data.residents;

    api.setVariable('Name1', Name[1]);
    api.setVariable('Name2', Name[2]);
    api.setVariable('Name3', Name[3]);
    api.setVariable('R1', Resident[1]);

  }
})();
```

But under the countries the residents' attributes are coming up as links like this:
[image]

I used POSTMAN here to test. When I click on the links I can see the person's attributes (e.g color, height, name, etc.). But How do I do that in JS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get the resident's data, you need to make a request to the endpoint and then use the returned data. for example to get the data of the first resident, you can make a request to `https://swapi.dev/api/people/1`.

This code makes requests for each resident.

```
(async () => {

  let Name = [];
  let Diameter = [];
  let Resident = [];

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    const PlanetDetails = await api.makeRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${[i]}`,
    });

    Name[i] = PlanetDetails.data.name;
    Resident[i] = await Promise.all(PlanetDetails.data.residents.map(async(resident) => {
        let resident = await api.makeRequest({
          method: 'GET',
          url: resident,
        });

        console.log(resident.data); // for visually viewing the result. 
        return resident.data;
    }));

    api.setVariable('Name1', Name[1]);
    api.setVariable('Name2', Name[2]);
    api.setVariable('Name3', Name[3]);
    api.setVariable('R1', Resident[1]);

  }
})();
```

Comment: Hi Khalil,

Thanks a lot for your comment! Where should I put your code in my code? Does that Need to be inside the for loop or outside?

Comment: It should be inside the `for` loop, after you make the request for the planet. Note that in my code, I only make a request but I don't do anything with the data.

Comment: Do I need to create another for loop for this?  Is this how it should be written inside the code? sorry I am new to this!

(async () => {

  let Name = [];
  let Diameter = [];
  let Resident = [];

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    const PlanetDetails = await api.makeRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${[i]}`,
    });
    Name[i] = PlanetDetails.data.name;
    Resident[i] = PlanetDetails.data.residents.forEach(async (resident) => {
      await api.makeRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: resident,
      });
    });
  }
})();

Comment: No need for a `for` loop, try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks Khalil. Tried that! But the data is empty. Coming up like this -> "{\"items\":[{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"},{\"item\":\"map[]\"}]}"

Comment: Can you show me the response in postman when requesting a resident?

Comment: Also the implementation of `api.makeRequest()`

Comment: /people/1

{
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "hair_color": "blond",
    "skin_color": "fair",
    "eye_color": "blue",
    "birth_year": "19BBY",
    "gender": "male",
    "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
    "films": [
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
    ],
    "species": [],
    "vehicles": [
        "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"

Comment: where do I find the implementation of api.makeRequest()?

Comment: What library are you using for making requests?

Comment: No using any library! I just wrote the code that I pasted above!

Comment: Check the updated answer. I was asking where does the `api.makeRequest()` come from?

Comment: oh sorry! That's mostly the company's internal library!

Comment: Is the code working now?

Comment: Hey Khalil,
Thank you so much for you help! Sorry for the delay! I checked the code! It's now coming up as like this for People (ID: 1) in the planet ->

{"items":[{"item":"map[birth_year:19BBY created:2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z edited:2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z eye_color:blue films:[https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/ https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/ https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/ and more! All the attributes as the SWAPI! 

How do I display only Attributes -> Name
Vehicles
Species
Eye colour?

Comment: you can simply use `Resident[index]['property_name']` such as `Resident[1]['name']`;